# Onload doesn't fire on "new Image()", when src is ".js" file

Tags: javascript

Am i wrong in assuming, that this should work?

```
var i = new Image();
i.onload = function () {
    alert('foo');
};
i.src = 'http://whatever.com/script.js';
```

This way onload event doesn't fire at all.
if i replace the last line with

```
i.src = 'http://somethingelse.com/image.png'
```

then it does. What could be the problem here? Does it only fire on image sources? What are the allowed content types then? Can't find any info on that.

Comment: I don't think it should be *too* surprising that an attempt to load a JavaScript source file as the contents of an image would cause a problem.

Comment: add event handler for `error`, then you would put out your problem

Comment: From doc -  `The requirements above imply that images can be static bitmaps (e.g. PNGs, GIFs, JPEGs), single-page vector documents (single-page PDFs, XML files with an SVG root element), animated bitmaps (APNGs, animated GIFs), animated vector graphics (XML files with an SVG root element that use declarative SMIL animation), and so forth. However, these definitions preclude SVG files with script, multipage PDF files, interactive MNG files, HTML documents, plain text documents, and so forth. [PNG] [GIF] [JPEG] [PDF] [XML] [APNG] [SVG] [MNG]`

Comment: That's what i needed. Thanks @ArunPJohny. Where did you find it, if I may ask?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140429/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element

Comment: @Pointy As far as I know, it is a way of performing XSS attacks in older browsers, so it doesn't seem that silly to me for someone to want to do something like that. If the `onload` event fires when a script loads through an image in older browsers, that I don't know.

Comment: @AlfonsoGarnett - I'm not sure if this was, but `<img onload="javascript:do bad stuff" src="valid_image.png" />` was

Comment: @AlfonsoGarnett oh I don't disagree with the notion that it's a simple way to get a browser to cache something, but it's just that a JavaScript file isn't an image. Maybe it's not so obvious that the "load" event is about the *successful* load and interpretation of the image source.

Comment: @adeneo Yeah, like that but through the `src` attribute also. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Script_in_IMG_tags
@Pointy Well, you'd of course expect that the load event fires when an *image*, through an `<img>` tag loads, but... *'Maybe it's not so obvious'* is a good way to put it, I guess. What I'm getting at is that I don't think this is a question that deserves two down-votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're getting an error when you try to load a javascript file as an image, and the `onerror` event probably fires instead.

The `onload` event only fires when an image was successfully loaded.

I'm guessing you can pass in almost any URL, as long as it's a valid image that **can be loaded** !

Comment: Ok, thanks, i kind of thought so, but what defines an image? What extension is it allowed to be in order for the browser to consider it a valid image?

Comment: I don't think it relies on extensions, but mime types and the fact that the browser actually is able to load the image.